# .Net XML reader does not detect all nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I cannot get the .NET XML reader to cooperate for anything. Here is my code:

```
public void downloadfile(string reqURL)
{
    HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqURL);
    // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
    webreq.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
    webreq.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
    //====================
    // Set credentials to use for this request.
    webreq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webreq.GetResponse();
    //====================
    // Get the stream associated with the response.
    XMLStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    Console.WriteLine("Response gotten");
    readStream = new StreamReader(XMLStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    settings.IgnoreComments = true;
    XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(readStream, settings);

    String title;
    String link;
    String descrip;
    int cut;
    for (; ; )
    {
        //get data
        reader.ReadToFollowing("title");
        title = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        reader.ReadToFollowing("link");
        link = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        reader.ReadToFollowing("description");
        descrip = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        //check if end of file.
        if (reader.EOF == true) { break; }
        if (title != "SimpleVoiceCenter message") 
        {
            String istribox;
            istribox = descrip.Substring(0, 20);
            if
                (
                istribox != "Voicebox number: 99." &&
                istribox != "Voicebox number: 88." &&
                istribox != "Voicebox number: 77."
                )
            {
                //Title =====
                Console.WriteLine("title: " + title);
                //Link =====
                Console.WriteLine("link: ...");
                //Descrip =====
                cut = descrip.IndexOf(".");
                if (cut < 0)
                {
                    cut = 20;
                }
                descrip = descrip.Remove(cut);
                if (descrip.EndsWith("."))
                {
                    descrip = descrip.Remove(cut - 1);
                }
                descrip = descrip.Replace("Voicebox number: ", "                 ");
                descrip = descrip.Trim();
                Console.WriteLine("voicebox: " + descrip);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            else { Console.WriteLine("skipping tribox"); }
        } else { Console.WriteLine("skipping title");}
    }
}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Simple Voice Center RSS feed</title>
        <link>http://www.simplevoicecenter.com</link>
        <description>This is the Simple Voice Center RSS feed. It allows an user to use the Podcasts technology to listen to voicebox messages.</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 29 Jan 2010 07:25:25 AM EST</lastBuildDate>

        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>0d84c8d1c4021254d63d45b0e0e52cd7</guid>
            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 0. Greeting had been recorded on June 06 2008 03:32:25 PM EDT. Greeting duration 00:03:06. File size:  1.42 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>

        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>bec76518968e65447da7a1e0641b69d8</guid>
            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 0. Name had been recorded on January 06 2008 11:06:45 PM EST. Name duration 00:00:02. File size:  0.02 MB.</description>

            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>889a47cda06094d0b36e39af33399dd3</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 1. Greeting had been recorded on September 19 2009 03:04:16 PM EDT. Greeting duration 00:02:16. File size:  1.04 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>cfd62ac51536fdbda52b4ddc37a3d58a</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 1. Name had been recorded on October 19 2006 05:04:02 PM EST. Name duration 00:00:03. File size:  0.03 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>4242a9aaef7b78568d47895894290664</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 2. Greeting had been recorded on July 09 2009 05:18:51 PM EDT. Greeting duration 00:07:30. File size:  3.44 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>4f3f85ac57a8834c816d840fef2c0a71</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 2. Name had been recorded on October 19 2006 05:07:12 PM EST. Name duration 00:00:04. File size:  0.03 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>f07c6b35551aa83c0a023e475f81a0b0</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 3. Greeting had been recorded on June 07 2007 12:23:32 PM EDT. Greeting duration 00:00:15. File size:  0.12 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>ad591ec5fe4e32a426c606a7bcc6b1e1</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 3. Name had been recorded on October 19 2006 05:09:02 PM EST. Name duration 00:00:03. File size:  0.03 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>2ea4df7f288289b9e8f92b3d7b485dc6</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 4. Greeting had been recorded on June 07 2007 12:26:54 PM EDT. Greeting duration 00:00:33. File size:  0.26 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>a61975f414447c852e85e2b83a4eeabc</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 4. Name had been recorded on October 19 2006 05:10:12 PM EST. Name duration 00:00:02. File size:  0.02 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>f7ee359afb2e2cc583df3d5c1b17fae4</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 5. Name had been recorded on June 07 2007 01:18:37 PM EDT. Name duration 00:01:04. File size:  0.50 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>15b0439f475f32f72b0bcb66d5f1d3ad</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 6. Name had been recorded on June 07 2007 01:37:40 PM EDT. Name duration 00:00:21. File size:  0.17 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>fcd6e34fdd010f2a7e71f0d75978a36a</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 6. Message had been recorded on December 30 2008 05:16:25 AM EST. Message duration 00:03:15. File size:  1.49 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>2b9dafd1e24e709830d5f337f38c147d</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 6. Message had been recorded on August 27 2009 04:39:10 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:29. File size:  0.22 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>e0ba0d02cb2592f0fafe9e1bf467a267</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 6. Message had been recorded on August 13 2008 08:22:20 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:18. File size:  0.14 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>603a1c9916261d4231d87cd007f1423a</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 6. Message had been recorded on August 13 2008 08:20:45 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:26. File size:  0.20 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>c3097857ad2b1b9422605d7efb4e04a4</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 7. Name had been recorded on June 07 2007 01:40:18 PM EDT. Name duration 00:00:12. File size:  0.10 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>7eff552b8c06ae5544fbe036e4691f0c</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 8. Name had been recorded on July 09 2009 05:15:33 PM EDT. Name duration 00:00:23. File size:  0.18 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User name</title>
            <guid>5adc9ad51f5c693d519fbf52d6cebc78</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 9. Name had been recorded on October 11 2006 05:49:18 PM EST. Name duration 00:00:00. File size:  0.01 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>90e641d04c6a1b7e5db8b82e56dca2ac</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Greeting had been recorded on September 21 2009 10:22:07 AM EDT. Greeting duration 00:00:29. File size:  0.22 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>c70337321783674e252a9a9ecc562053</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on January 08 2010 07:54:17 PM EST. Message duration 00:00:07. File size:  0.05 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>7d71887b4b401448c616f678f37e5d72</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on June 20 2009 05:02:06 PM EDT. Message duration 00:01:50. File size:  0.84 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>1bace556c868965f80d86c3c5cf26728</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on August 29 2009 09:43:03 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:47. File size:  0.36 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>93e5560aef94f84cb04cf158bf5e7a9a</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on July 16 2009 05:31:31 AM EDT. Message duration 00:00:26. File size:  0.20 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>8d14eb04665fd48fb2567be75440e9d7</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on June 20 2009 04:58:54 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:55. File size:  0.42 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>cfb0843a7d7bc22fc6771553b07d4c42</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on June 14 2009 09:54:59 AM EDT. Message duration 00:01:38. File size:  0.75 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>d563663a620fefa507a5add7fa5348a1</guid>

            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on January 05 2009 04:11:41 PM EST. Message duration 00:01:05. File size:  0.50 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>

            <guid>a680314acbc74572c1a6d5b514fe2c42</guid>
            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on September 05 2008 09:30:41 AM EDT. Message duration 00:01:18. File size:  0.60 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>

            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>f99b55053d0da8a4f1e475af45f9abaf</guid>
            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on August 22 2008 11:48:11 PM EDT. Message duration 00:01:01. File size:  0.47 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>83c17b59f0c9da70265a96f19c44a306</guid>
            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on August 20 2008 11:49:31 AM EDT. Message duration 00:00:26. File size:  0.20 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>

        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>134b015a223f01d973956ad1678cd666</guid>
            <link>...</link>
            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on August 19 2008 10:07:07 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:04. File size:  0.03 MB.</description>

            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>bd290e914806a29f9f9c53758e4adfbc</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on July 23 2008 12:21:49 AM EDT. Message duration 00:01:06. File size:  0.51 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>6d11dd122a7ca9f82a9b6117e011fe28</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on June 19 2008 10:22:51 PM EDT. Message duration 00:01:17. File size:  0.59 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>e8ffc169d93d0dce22c0cc5e63084326</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on May 05 2008 12:35:28 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:33. File size:  0.26 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>e1346a4e13987a5966a0abb3359a30d3</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on December 02 2007 07:10:32 PM EST. Message duration 00:00:26. File size:  0.20 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>13dd8477337077e039194414acfa6e64</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on September 02 2007 02:21:50 PM EDT. Message duration 00:01:42. File size:  0.78 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>SimpleVoiceCenter message</title>
            <guid>f9b5b040eeea90262712f3e6a94fb980</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 99. Message had been recorded on September 01 2007 03:45:41 PM EDT. Message duration 00:00:34. File size:  0.27 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>07d99563b8a253804dfd663851cf3dfb</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 88. Greeting had been recorded on September 21 2009 10:22:28 AM EDT. Greeting duration 00:01:31. File size:  0.70 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>User greeting</title>
            <guid>a28645b32628cc854e3c978003217f1f</guid>
            <link>...</link>

            <description>Voicebox number: 77. Greeting had been recorded on September 21 2009 10:22:40 AM EDT. Greeting duration 00:00:48. File size:  0.37 MB.</description>
            <author>Free Conference Call</author>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is my Console output:

```
Response gotten
title: Simple Voice Center RSS feed
link: ...
voicebox: 0

title: User greeting
link: ...
voicebox: 1

title: User greeting
link: ...
voicebox: 2

title: User greeting
link: ...
voicebox: 3

title: User greeting
link: ...
voicebox: 4

title: User name //This should be here but is not
link: ...        //
voicebox: 5      //

title: User name
link: ...
voicebox: 6

skipping title
skipping title

title: User name //This should also be here, but is not
link: ...        //
voicebox: 7      //

title: User name
link: ...
voicebox: 8

skipping tribox
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
skipping title
Done
```

Update: Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should try to explain what exactly are you trying to read from this RSS file and what is the expected output.

Comment: (continuing Darin's comment) ...highlighting where actual differs from expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why note use XML serialization for what it is. Looping over the nodes doesn't seem like the right way to handle this.
Try creating a class for the information you need (quick mock-up):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("rss")]
public class MyRss
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("channel")]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }

    ...
}

[Serializable]
public class Channel
{
    [XmlElement("version")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

and then deserialize the string into this class and use that to create your output:

```
public static MyRss Deserialize(string xmlString) 
{
   var obj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyRss)).Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));
   return (MyRss)obj;
}
```

then use this object to output what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: After more research, I think this is what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing and reading XML, LinqToXml is a great improvement over XmlReader.